# Pourquoi certains posts sur Facebook sont-ils masculins/féminins?

Tags: genre

Ce post a été "vue":
[image: Une poste sur Facebook qui a été vue par 5 personnes]

Et ce post a été "vu":
[image: Une poste sur Facebook qui a été "vu", sans "e", par tout le monde]

Est-ce que quelqu'un sait pourquoi?

Comment: Qu'est-ce que c'est que le premier? Personnellement, il y a toujours écrit "vu" sur mon Facebook, ce qui est logique vu que c'est *un* post.

Answer (score 4):

Facebook traduit l'anglais *post* par publication qui est un mot féminin, donc **une** publication est **vue**.

Un commentaire apporté à une publication est masculin donc, **un** commentaire est **vu**.

Une publication est aussi parfois appelée *un post* en français (jamais *une poste*). La documentation de Facebook considère parfois quelque chose de publié comme non nommé ou comme **un** message et dans ce cas, c'est le masculin qui est utilisé "(Ceci a été) **vu** par xxx".

Références:

https://www.facebook.com/help/409719555736128

https://www.facebook.com/help/work/1616944214986037

Answer (score 0):

Ce mot en Français métropolitain est masculin selon le [Wiktionaire](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/post) et [l'internaute](https://www.linternaute.fr/dictionnaire/fr/definition/post/).
Cependant, il a une autre orthographe : *post**e*** (voir le Wiktionaire). Cette orthographe est probablement due au mot d'origine française plus ancien, « poste » (« post » est un néologisme provenant de l'anglais) qui signifie entre autre « organisme de distribution du courrier »  et « position ». Comme le e final est souvent la marque du féminin en français certaines personnes doivent être  portées à croire qu'il s'agit d'un féminin, mais c'est une erreur. Parmi les usagers du FSE il n'y a personne qui utilise ce mot au féminin.

Comment: On peut connaitre la raison du vote négatif ?

Comment: Pas mon vote (pour une fois...) mais tu es à côté de la plaque. Ce texte n'est pas écrit par les utilisateurs mais produit par le logiciel, donc on ne peut pas attribuer le genre à une erreur des utilisateurs. Tu dis aussi que *poste* est un mot qui signifie *organisme de distribution du courrier* et *position* alors qu'il s'agit de deux mots différents, le premier étant féminin et le deuxième masculin. Tu dis aussi qu'aucun usager de FSE n'utilise *post(e)* (dans le sens de message posté sur Internet) au féminin alors que Jean démontre le contraire...